# Folder I didn't create with numbers and letters in secondary drive. What it is and what is safer to do?

Tags: windows, security, windows-explorer

In Windows 10 (but by seeing "Date Modified" I guess it was there when I was using Win 8.1) there's a folder in the secondary drive (my laptop has two) I just use for Windows File History (Windows backup):

[image: The strange folder]

Kaspersky doesn't detect it as a virus. Does anyone know what it is, and if it is save to keep it and to delete it?

This is its content:

[image]

I can't see any of the subfolders. Even clicking "OK" in the message displayed to have permanent access to the folder leads me to this other message:

[image]

Clicking the security tab and then "Advance":

[image]

Even in "Advance" it says it is unable to see the current owner, but this level is too much to mess with for my knowledge. I would just like to know what it is and what would be safer, to hide it or to delete it?

Comment: PS: The folder was not hidden or marked as a protected operating system file by default (I keep both types hidden).

Comment: this is a temporary folder of C++ Runtime setup. take ownership of the folder (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753659.aspx) to be able to delete it.

Comment: Looking at the directory name `vstor40`, it is likely that this is a temporary installation folder for _Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime_. The numeric folder names are typically localisation files for different languages - see the **LCID Dec** column [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/bb964664.aspx). As such it can almost certainly be deleted, but whether you can find the privileges to do so is another matter: you may need to use a recovery disc if all else fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a result / leftovers of a [.NET installation](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/242767-strange-folders-c-drive.html).

The installers for the .NET Framework use a self-extracting logic for these versions of the .NET Framework does the following:

- Find the drive on your system with the largest amount of free disk space
- Create a randomly named folder on that drive
- Extract the contents of the EXE to that folder
- Run the setup EXE from within that folder
- After the setup EXE returns, attempt to delete that folder

Normally it disappears after rebooting, but there are many cases it doesn't. Every attempt in deleting it mostly fail as it request us to have permission though we are the administrator. Some attempt were done by taking ownership of folders and files but unsuccessful.

In order to remove it try [Extended Disk Cleanup](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/76383-disk-cleanup-extended.html).

Comment: Trying it @duDE, thanks. I'll let you know it it worked and will mark your answer.

Comment: Disk Cleanup Settings shows several options to delete. Do you know which one would be the one to use for this case?  This is the list of options (Files to delete): [see next comment. No space left here]

Comment: Temporary Setup Files;  
Old Chkdsk files;   
Setup Log Files;   
Windows Update Cleanup;   
Windows Defender;   
Windows upgrade Log files;   
Downloaded Program Files;   
Temporary Intemet Files;   
System error memory dump files;   
System error minidump files;   
Files discarded by Windows upgrade;   
Per user archived Windows Exor Reporting Files;   
Per user queued Windows Error Reporting Files;   
System archived Windows Error Reporting Files;   
System queued Windows Error Reporting Files;   
System archived Windows Error Reporting Files;

Comment: Windows ESD installation files;  
 BranchCache;  
 Previous Windows installation(s);  
 Recycle Bin;  
 Retail Demo Offline Contert;  
 Update package Backup Files;  
 Temporary files;  
 Temporary Windows installation files;  
 Thumbnails;  
 User file history.

Comment: All the listed files can be safe removed. But for sure  "Temporary Setup Files", "System Restore and Shadow Copies", "Temporary Files", "Downloaded Program Files" ...

Comment: Have tried the ones you mentioned except "System Restore" as I want to keep the restore points in case something happens to my system. It didn't delete the folder. Maybe any of the other options I posted? If it is not clear which one it is and it is clear it is safe to keep it, I might just hide the folder so that it doesn't mess with my syncing file system and other stuff.

Comment: To hide the folder is surely the safest way :)

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll do that unless I have another suggestion. I'd value answers to: is it clear it is the result of a .NET installation? Which particular option in the Cleanup utility to delete? Is there another likely reason for this folder to exist?

Comment: Mmm, by they way, I guess the "C:\" in "C:\WINDOWS\system32>" is all right even though the folder is in "D:", but shouldn't I change the "/c" in "%SystemRoot%\System32\Cmd.exe /c Cleanmgr /sageset:65535 & Cleanmgr /sagerun:65535" in the CMD for a "/d"?